# Can't delete a task from a todo list

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I am pretty new to JavaScript and I'm trying to make a todo list where you can add new tasks and delete them everytime you click on the submit and delete button.
I was doing so far so good until it came to the delete button. When I click on it, it doesn't delete the actual element from the object. I THINK the mistake is somewhere in the code where I iterate through the array with map and create a new id to each task, but I haven't been able to figure out where...

I would really appreciate it if you guys can find where the mistake is...!

```js
//empty array:
let todoList = [];

//get elements from HTML:
let newTask = document.querySelector("#addTask");
let form = document.querySelector(".form");
let list = document.querySelector("#list");
let val = document.querySelector("#priority");

//Event Listeners:
form.addEventListener("submit", getData);
list.addEventListener("click", deleteTask);

//Functions:
//1. get the data from the form:
function getData(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //create a new object:
  const task = {
    name: newTask.value,
    p: val.value
  };
  //clean input
  newTask.value = "";

  //add net task to todoList array:
  todoList = [...todoList, task];

  //add id to each item:
  let i = 0;
  todoList.map((task) => {
    task["id"] = i + 1;
    i++;
  });

  toHtml(todoList);
}

//2. add the task to HTML:
function toHtml(data) {
  //clean the HTML:
  while (list.firstChild) {
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
  }

  todoList.forEach((item) => {
    const { name, p, id } = item;
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("new-task");
    div.innerHTML = `<p>${name}<span> (${p})</span></p> 
                     <a href="#" class="delete-btn" id=${id}>X</a>`;
    list.appendChild(div);
  });
}

//Delete data from Form:
function deleteTask(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.classList.contains("delete-btn")) {
    let deleteId = e.target.getAttribute("id");
    console.log(deleteId);
    todoList = todoList.filter((task) => {
      return task.id !== deleteId;
    });
    console.log(todoList);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.form {
margin: 0 auto; 

.list {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.new-task {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Todo list</h1>

    <form class="form">
      <label for="addTask">Add a task</label>
      <input type="text" class="addTask" id="addTask" />
      <select name="priority" id="priority">
        <option value="p1" id="p1">P1</option>
        <option value="p2" id="p2">P2</option>
        <option value="p3" id="p3">P3</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Add" id="submit" />
    </form>

    <div class="list" id="list"></div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could include the relevant HTML in the snippet and actually make it runnable.

Comment: You change the ID of every task every time you add a task, but you never change the ID in `<a href="#" class="delete-btn" id=${id}>X</a>`.  Also, instead of the `let i = 0` etc., simply use `.map((task, i) => task.id = i + 1)`.

Comment: Managing unique IDs yourself can be tricky. You could try to run the same `map` after deletion so the IDs are kept consistent, but this comes at a performance cost. You could work with [`Map`s](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead, e.g. `const map = new Map();`, then when you create your `<div>`, use `map.set(div, item);`. When deleting, check `if(event.target.closest(".delete-btn")){ const deleteID = map.get(event.target.closest("div")).id;` _etc._ `}`.

Comment: @Wyck Yeah, you are right! I'm sorry, I just added it

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thank you for your comment. I will try to add the code you provided and see if it works!